# RStudio keeps bugging me with the "cacheKey" error

Tags: r, function, rstudio, assign, invalid-argument

Even before updating RStudio to its lattest version, I am constant (like every 5 minutes) getting this error message

```
"Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
Error in assign(cacheKey, frame, .rs.CachedDataEnv) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name"
```

The only thing that seems to work is quitting RStudio and opening again.
That is very annoying becase I lose all my previous stuff that I need to continue my analyses.
Does anyone know how to get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is fixed in RStudio versions 2023.06.1-524 and later.

Refer https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13188.